# DisplayPort with unpowered sink: EDID possible?

Tags: displayport

When using dvi or hdmi, the source provides 5V to power an eeprom inside a monitor or any other sink, reading the edid back and setting the resolution accordingly. That is possible because both dvi and hdmi have separate ddc/i2C lines and a power supply to drive it.

Now when I look at displayport, there's the aux channel which serves the same purpose, among others. But the sink system has to be powered or at least plugged into the wall socket, providing standby power.

Imagine you want to build a monitor that, if unpowered, does not disrupt the desktop settings of windows. Is there a way to attach an eeprom orsomething else that does the job to the dp aux channel?

Comment: If you don't need the extra bandwidth offered by DP, you could use the fallback HDMI compatible mode and just connect it to an HDMI sink. I believe that mode is required to implement every feature of HDMI, including the power supply for the EDID. Of course that doesn't help if you *do* need the extra bandwidth, but it's still something you could consider!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking this from wrong direction.

Since it is not possible for a monitor to communicate without power there is no EDID available.

Since anything is possible, of course you can design a monitor with backup battery to power the AUX channel section, but it would not be practical.

You could also design a powered box to work as an EDID emulator for an unpowered display. These might already exist.

In real life, you would just configure your Windows drivers so that they ignore missing displays, many drivers have settings for ignoring displays and EDID forcing, so there is no need to add or design any special hardware.

Comment: That is true. But my intention was, is there anything that can be attached directly to the aux channel that runs with the provided 5V, and provides said edid?

Comment: @PhreakShow What provided 5V?

Comment: My bad, meant the 3.3V at pin 20.

Comment: @PhreakShow Well you could use it to power something that can intercept the AUX channel without disturbing normal operation, but it would still be under my original suggestion of building an externally powered box, but in dongle form.

Comment: And what would that something be? I didn't find anything that interfaces directly with the aux and serves as an EEPROM, except like a ptn3460 but thats pretty much overkill.

Comment: @PhreakShow Tried to find existing DisplayPort EDID emulator dongles?

Comment: Yes, but they are never opened to have a look at the inside.

Comment: @PhreakShow But that's not the point, if they work, you can just buy one and use it, no need to spend time thinking if it is possible or not or how it works. As you can't integrate it into the display in any way as there is no power for it.

Comment: But that exactly the point. I want to build something that acts as a monitor and that's why I want to know how it works.